# How to set the maximum and minimum scale of the x-axis of a histogram?

Tags: excel, vba, histogram

I am trying to set my histograms to have a maximum and minimum scale as they are many zeros at the start and the end for some of my histograms. I was using

```
    With Activechart.Axes(xlCategory)
        .MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Bnum, -1)
        .MinimumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Snum, -1)
    End With
```

to try and set it where `Snum` is the smallest number and `Bnum` is the largest in the selected range.
However there was a

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method of 'MaximumScale' of object 'Axis' failed

So i was thinking, is it possible to set the scale for a histogram or do i have to change the bin and range to solve this. Please advise, thank you.

If it is helpful, here is my full code to plot my histograms

```
Sub MakeHistogram()

    Dim src_sheet As Worksheet, Graph_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim selected_range As Range
    Dim title As String
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim percent_cell As Range
    Dim num_percent As Integer
    Dim count_range As Range, bin_range As Range
    Dim new_chart As Chart
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long, glRow As Long
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim RngToCover As Range, Chtob As ChartObject
    Dim Snum As Long, Bnum As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
    End With

    With Sheets("Data")
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    For i = 5 To lCol

        With Sheets("Data")
            Set selected_range = .Range(.Cells(6, i), .Cells(lRow, i))
        End With
        Set src_sheet = Sheets("Data")
        Set Graph_sheet = Sheets("Graphs")
        title = src_sheet.Cells(2, i).Value

        With Graph_sheet
            glRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If glRow = 2 Then glRow = glRow - 1
            .Cells(glRow + 1, 1) = title
            .Cells(glRow + 1, 1).Font.Bold = True
        End With
        xStr = src_sheet.Cells(5, i).Value
        If xStr = "%" Then xStr = "Percentage %"

        num_percent = selected_range.Count

        ' See how many bins we will have.
        Const BIN_SIZE As Integer = 5
        Dim num_bins As Integer
        num_bins = 150 \ BIN_SIZE

        ' Make the bin separators.
        Graph_sheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Bins"

        For r = 1 To num_bins - 1
            Graph_sheet.Cells(r + 2, 2) = r * BIN_SIZE - 1
        Next r

        ' Make the counts.
        Graph_sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Counts"
        Set count_range = Graph_sheet.Range("A" & glRow + 2 & ":A" & num_bins + glRow)
        Set bin_range = Graph_sheet.Range("B" & 3 & ":B" & num_bins)

        count_range = WorksheetFunction.Frequency(selected_range, bin_range)

        ' Make the range labels.

        Graph_sheet.Cells(1, 3) = "Ranges"
        For r = 1 To num_bins - 1
            Graph_sheet.Cells(r + 2, 3) = "'" & _
                5 * (r - 1) & "-" & _
                  5 * (r - 1) + 4
            Graph_sheet.Cells(r + 2, 3).HorizontalAlignment = _
                xlRight
        Next r
        r = num_bins
        Graph_sheet.Cells(r + 1, 3) = "'" & _
            5 * (r - 1) & "-150"
        Graph_sheet.Cells(r + 1, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

        ' Make the chart.
        Set new_chart = Charts.Add()
        With new_chart
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData Source:=Graph_sheet.Range("A" & glRow + 2 & ":A" & _
                num_bins + glRow + 1), _
                PlotBy:=xlColumns
            .Location where:=xlLocationAsObject, _
                Name:="Graphs"
        End With

        'Get the largest and smallest number
        Snum = 100
        Bnum = 0
        For Each cell In selected_range
            With cell
                If .Value < Snum Then Snum = .Value
                If .Value > Bnum Then Bnum = .Value
            End With
        Next cell

        With Graph_sheet
            Set RngToCover = .Range(.Cells(glRow + 5, 5), .Cells(glRow + 22, 11))
        End With

        With ActiveChart
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = title & " Histogram"
            With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
                .HasTitle = True
                .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = xStr
            End With
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Count"

            ' Display percentage ranges on the X axis.
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & _
                "Graphs" & "'!R3C3:R" & _
                num_bins + 1 & "C3"

            Set Chtob = .Parent
            Chtob.Height = RngToCover.Height
            Chtob.Width = RngToCover.Width
            Chtob.Top = RngToCover.Top
            Chtob.Left = RngToCover.Left
            With .Axes(xlCategory)
                'Error starts here
                .MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Bnum, -1) 
                .MinimumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Snum, -1)
            End With
        End With
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
        With ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1)
            .Overlap = 0
            .GapWidth = 0
            .HasSeriesLines = False
            .VaryByCategories = False
        End With
    Next i
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
    End With
End sub
```

This code loops through the columns of data in the data sheet and get the frequency of each columns, which consist of a few hundred data, and get the counts for it to make a histogram in the graph sheet for each columns of data.

Do clarify with me if you need more details, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.axis.minimumscale) `MaximumScale` and `MinimumScale` are not available for x-axis (xlCategory) but only for y-axis (xlValue). So you need to change the range.